# Running Shapiro-Wilk test on columns of a dataframe, skipping factors

Tags: r, distribution

I have a following data frame:

```
alpha<-rnorm(100,40)
beta<-sort(1:100)
gamma<-sample(30:75,100,replace=T)
delta<-c(rep("A",25),rep("B",25),rep("C",25),rep("D",25))
df<-as.data.frame(cbind(alpha,beta,gamma,delta))
```

I can apply `shapiro.test` to individual columns, and see whether the p value is less than 0.05 like this:

```
shapiro.test(alpha)
shapiro.test(alpha)$p.value<0.05
```

But I was wondering whether I can do this in batch, applying `shapiro.test` to each column in the data frame that consist of continuous data (skipping columns consisting of factors). The way I imagined this is:

```
shapiro.test(names(df))
which(shapiro.test(names(df))$p.value<0.05)
```

But it did not work. Any suggestions? I would rather avoid looping if possible.

Comment: how about this sapply(df, function(x) shapiro.test(x)$p.value<0.05 )

Comment: It works. I run into a problem though - if the `x` contains a column with factors, then the code does not work. I updated the dataframe code above to reflect this. Would there be a way to "skip" the column whenever it does not work?

Comment: Regarding the revised question and data set:  Will you know in advance which columns are factors?  Would it be acceptable to simply subset the data frame before running the Shapiro test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you can write a little custom function and use it like this:

```
alpha<-round(rnorm(100,40))
beta<-sort(1:100)
gamma<-sample(30:75,100,replace=T)
df<-as.data.frame(cbind(alpha,beta,gamma))

myfun <- function(x) res <- shapiro.test(x)$p.value
apply(df, 2, myfun)
```

The way you were calling `shapiro.test` in your example was not using the data frame, it was using the value of `alpha` in the workspace.

Check out `?apply` for details.

EDIT: If your data set contains factors, here is one means of skipping over them (note: I modified your data set):

```
alpha<-rnorm(100,40)
beta<-sort(1:100)
gamma<-sample(30:75,100,replace=T)
delta<-c(rep("A",25),rep("B",25),rep("C",25),rep("D",25))
df<-data.frame(alpha,beta,gamma,delta)

ans <- rep(NA, ncol(df))
for (i in 1:ncol(df)) {
    if (is.factor(df[,i])) next
    ans[i] <- shapiro.test(df[,i])$p.value
    }
```

Then type `ans` to see the results.

Comment: this works too. I edited the last line of your slightly to get what I wanted `which(apply(df, 2, myfun)<0.05)` .The problem is, it does not work if the dataframe contains even a single column with factors and the only output I get is `Error: is.numeric(x) is not TRUE`. Is there a way to make it skip the column(s) with factors and only include the columns with continuous data in its output?

Comment: The suggested edits you made to my answer either should be made to your original question, or better, ask a new question along the lines of "How can I skip columns consisting of factors".  In any case, I'll edit my answer to show you how.

Comment: Did the example with factors accomplish what you wanted?

Comment: many thanks, but your example just lists p values without knowing which columns they belong to. I deally I would have them with column names, or just columns names. I tried to substitute the last line of your code with `ans[i] <- which(shapiro.test(df[,i])$p.value<0.05)`but it did not work. Regarding my edits to your asnwer - that was a mistake, I thought I was editing my own question.

Comment: Ah, you keep moving the goal post! ;-)  You can easily add the names by doing `names(ans) <- colnames(df)` before you do the loop.  Or, you could do `res <- data.frame(variable = colnames(df), p.value = ans)` after you run the loop, to have all your results in a single object.

Comment: wow, that did the trick! plus, at the end of your code, adding `ans<0.05` lists everything perfectly. Thanks again.